# auto page height on horizontal divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, height

I have a one page site with the sections sweeping in horizontally.

The problem I have is that I want the page to be a the size of the content of the current div, but the page height gets set to the height of the biggest div and on the smaller divs there is a huge footer.

I have tried to use height auto on the divs but that doesnt seem to make any difference

heres a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qnbBS/30/

and a live example with the horizontal sweeping divs: [live example](http://97squared.co.uk/starstruck-roadshow.co.uk/)

you can see that page 3  has a vast amount of text and the footer sits at the bottom on the page, but on page one and page two the footer is huge to fill the gap. 
I am trying to find a way of making the footer an equal size(say 75px) and for it so sit at the bottom of each page and for there to be no extra space on pages with less content.

code to match demo

css

```
html, body {
height: auto;
margin: 0;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
.wrapper {
width: 300%;
height: auto;
background: #263729;
}
.page {
width: 33.3333%;
float:left;
background: #992213;
min-height: auto;
}
#page-1 {
background: #0C717A;
}
#page-2 {
background: #009900;
}
#page-3 {
background: #0000FF;
}
a {
color:#FFF;
}
.footer {
background:red; 
}
.simulate {
height:auto;
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="page-1" class="page"> <a href="#page-1" class="scrollitem selected">page 1</a>  <a href="#page-2" class="scrollitem">page 2</a>
 <a href="#page-3" class="scrollitem">page 3</a>

     <h3>page 1</h3>

     <div class="simulate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi imperdiet ante et neque finibus, et facilisis urna pulvinar. Curabitur tempus tempus nisi, a hendrerit nisi dapibus sed. Aliquam rutrum varius ex eu elementum. Etiam et venenatis tortor, vel lobortis metus. Ut vitae tortor eget sapien sagittis bibendum a ac magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam turpis purus, lacinia vel pharetra vel, dignissim at lorem. Maecenas felis elit, viverra at augue luctus, rutrum molestie leo.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="page-2" class="page"> <a href="#page-1" class="scrollitem selected">page 1</a>
    <a href="#page-2" class="scrollitem">page 2</a>
    <a href="#page-3" class="scrollitem">page 3</a>

     <h3>page 2</h3>

    <div class="simulate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi imperdiet ante et neque finibus, et facilisis urna pulvinar. Curabitur tempus tempus nisi, a hendrerit nisi dapibus sed. Aliquam rutrum varius ex eu elementum. Etiam et venenatis tortor, vel lobortis metus. Ut vitae tortor eget sapien sagittis bibendum a ac magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam turpis purus, lacinia vel pharetra vel, dignissim at lorem. Maecenas felis elit, viverra at augue luctus, rutrum molestie leo. Donec a auctor est. Fusce vel lacus vehicula, rhoncus nulla nec, iaculis orci. Etiam tellus urna, iaculis eget lobortis ac, porttitor ut metus. Etiam et tempus neque, eu feugiat nibh. Nulla imperdiet magna dolor. Mauris ac varius risus, sed commodo tortor. Nullam dictum imperdiet libero, sit amet euismod augue tristique at. Praesent feugiat lectus et tempor dictum. Duis rutrum ligula quis urna euismod aliquet. Sed blandit gravida tortor, ac molestie augue sodales sed. Morbi bibendum est aliquet dolor porttitor sollicitudin. Nam fringilla et odio vel blandit. Curabitur egestas iaculis odio sit amet volutpat. Aliquam placerat tellus sed turpis tincidunt, et ornare nunc facilisis. Mauris tincidunt ac tortor nec tincidunt. Cras velit nibh, scelerisque a pulvinar consequat, vehicula a sem. Sed ultricies metus sit amet feugiat egestas. Cras eget aliquam sem. Sed sit amet purus dapibus, tristique justo at, lobortis ligula. Nam vitae ligula in magna molestie iaculis. Vivamus gravida placerat dapibus. Mauris eget molestie elit, facilisis rutrum nunc. Vivamus suscipit, nisl sed varius eleifend, dui erat semper diam, vel elementum neque lacus a ante. Nulla varius iaculis egestas. Quisque porttitor lacinia tristique.</div>
</div>
<div id="page-3" class="page"> 
    <a href="#page-1" class="scrollitem selected">page 1</a>
    <a href="#page-2" class="scrollitem">page 2</a>
    <a href="#page-3" class="scrollitem">page 3</a>

     <h3>page 3</h3>

    <div class="simulate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi imperdiet ante et neque finibus, et facilisis urna pulvinar. Curabitur tempus tempus nisi, a hendrerit nisi dapibus sed. Aliquam rutrum varius ex eu elementum. Etiam et venenatis tortor, vel lobortis metus. Ut vitae tortor eget sapien sagittis bibendum a ac magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam turpis purus, lacinia vel pharetra vel, dignissim at lorem. Maecenas felis elit, viverra at augue luctus, rutrum molestie leo. Donec a auctor est. Fusce vel lacus vehicula, rhoncus nulla nec, iaculis orci. Etiam tellus urna, iaculis eget lobortis ac, porttitor ut metus. Etiam et tempus neque, eu feugiat nibh. Nulla imperdiet magna dolor. Mauris ac varius risus, sed commodo tortor. Nullam dictum imperdiet libero, sit amet euismod augue tristique at. Praesent feugiat lectus et tempor dictum. Duis rutrum ligula quis urna euismod aliquet. Sed blandit gravida tortor, ac molestie augue sodales sed. Morbi bibendum est aliquet dolor porttitor sollicitudin. Nam fringilla et odio vel blandit. Curabitur egestas iaculis odio sit amet volutpat. Aliquam placerat tellus sed turpis tincidunt, et ornare nunc facilisis. Mauris tincidunt ac tortor nec tincidunt. Cras velit nibh, scelerisque a pulvinar consequat, vehicula a sem. Sed ultricies metus sit amet feugiat egestas. Cras eget aliquam sem. Sed sit amet purus dapibus, tristique justo at, lobortis ligula. Nam vitae ligula in magna molestie iaculis. Vivamus gravida placerat dapibus. Mauris eget molestie elit, facilisis rutrum nunc. Vivamus suscipit, nisl sed varius eleifend, dui erat semper diam, vel elementum neque lacus a ante. Nulla varius iaculis egestas. Quisque porttitor lacinia tristique. Aliquam ornare nibh sit amet tortor rhoncus, id accumsan nulla feugiat. Nunc pellentesque consectetur dapibus. Vestibulum sit amet lobortis augue. Cras justo nisl, ultricies molestie congue ut, ultrices et velit. Nam consectetur ligula vehicula consectetur dapibus. Etiam tempor condimentum massa quis dictum. Nunc semper, nunc quis tincidunt auctor, ipsum massa cursus lectus, accumsan posuere lectus magna eget lorem. Maecenas non vehicula libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla imperdiet eros at magna mattis, et interdum metus rutrum. Sed semper sed odio sit amet tempor. Aenean sed odio efficitur, congue ligula nec, tempor augue. Nam nec tristique arcu. Aenean aliquam mollis tincidunt. Maecenas et leo quis ex aliquet euismod. Sed et ex eget nisl varius finibus. Aliquam nec lorem in massa venenatis gravida. Quisque non nibh sed diam pretium ultricies in imperdiet nulla. Fusce eget ornare elit. Mauris id mauris eget ante tempus mattis. Nam non aliquam lorem, nec egestas urna. Quisque consequat libero vitae ligula consectetur imperdiet. Vestibulum nec bibendum felis, quis imperdiet dui. Phasellus viverra ornare sem, sit amet rutrum nisi. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ex, at sagittis lectus imperdiet at. Donec vel nulla sem. Praesent quis aliquam arcu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi imperdiet ante et neque finibus, et facilisis urna pulvinar. Curabitur tempus tempus nisi, a hendrerit nisi dapibus sed. Aliquam rutrum varius ex eu elementum. Etiam et venenatis tortor, vel lobortis metus. Ut vitae tortor eget sapien sagittis bibendum a ac magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam turpis purus, lacinia vel pharetra vel, dignissim at lorem. Maecenas felis elit, viverra at augue luctus, rutrum molestie leo. Donec a auctor est. Fusce vel lacus vehicula, rhoncus nulla nec, iaculis orci. Etiam tellus urna, iaculis eget lobortis ac, porttitor ut metus. Etiam et tempus neque, eu feugiat nibh. Nulla imperdiet magna dolor. Mauris ac varius risus, sed commodo tortor. Nullam dictum imperdiet libero, sit amet euismod augue tristique at. Praesent feugiat lectus et tempor dictum. Duis rutrum ligula quis urna euismod aliquet. Sed blandit gravida tortor, ac molestie augue sodales sed. Morbi bibendum est aliquet dolor porttitor sollicitudin. Nam fringilla et odio vel blandit. Curabitur egestas iaculis odio sit amet volutpat. Aliquam placerat tellus sed turpis tincidunt, et ornare nunc facilisis. Mauris tincidunt ac tortor nec tincidunt. Cras velit nibh, scelerisque a pulvinar consequat, vehicula a sem. Sed ultricies metus sit amet feugiat egestas. Cras eget aliquam sem. Sed sit amet purus dapibus, tristique justo at, lobortis ligula. Nam vitae ligula in magna molestie iaculis. Vivamus gravida placerat dapibus. Mauris eget molestie elit, facilisis rutrum nunc. Vivamus suscipit, nisl sed varius eleifend, dui erat semper diam, vel elementum neque lacus a ante. Nulla varius iaculis egestas. Quisque porttitor lacinia tristique. Aliquam ornare nibh sit amet tortor rhoncus, id accumsan nulla feugiat. Nunc pellentesque consectetur dapibus. Vestibulum sit amet lobortis augue. Cras justo nisl, ultricies molestie congue ut, ultrices et velit. Nam consectetur ligula vehicula consectetur dapibus. Etiam tempor condimentum massa quis dictum. Nunc semper, nunc quis tincidunt auctor, ipsum massa cursus lectus, accumsan posuere lectus magna eget lorem. Maecenas non vehicula libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla imperdiet eros at magna mattis, et interdum metus rutrum. Sed semper sed odio sit amet tempor. Aenean sed odio efficitur, congue ligula nec, tempor augue. Nam nec tristique arcu. Aenean aliquam mollis tincidunt. Maecenas et leo quis ex aliquet euismod. Sed et ex eget nisl varius finibus. Aliquam nec lorem in massa venenatis gravida. Quisque non nibh sed diam pretium ultricies in imperdiet nulla. Fusce eget ornare elit. Mauris id mauris eget ante tempus mattis. Nam non aliquam lorem, nec egestas urna. Quisque consequat libero vitae ligula conLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi imperdiet ante et neque finibus, et facilisis urna pulvinar. Curabitur tempus tempus nisi, a hendrerit nisi dapibus sed. Aliquam rutrum varius ex eu elementum. Etiam et venenatis tortor, vel lobortis metus. Ut vitae tortor eget sapien sagittis bibendum a ac magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam turpis purus, lacinia vel pharetra vel, dignissim at lorem. Maecenas felis elit, viverra at augue luctus, rutrum molestie leo. Donec a auctor est. Fusce vel lacus vehicula, rhoncus nulla nec, iaculis orci. Etiam tellus urna, iaculis eget lobortis ac, porttitor ut metus. Etiam et tempus neque, eu feugiat nibh. Nulla imperdiet magna dolor. Mauris ac varius risus, sed commodo tortor. Nullam dictum imperdiet libero, sit amet euismod augue tristique at. Praesent feugiat lectus et tempor dictum. Duis rutrum ligula quis urna euismod aliquet. Sed blandit gravida tortor, ac molestie augue sodales sed. Morbi bibendum est aliquet dolor porttitor sollicitudin. Nam fringilla et odio vel blandit. Curabitur egestas iaculis odio sit amet volutpat. Aliquam placerat tellus sed turpis tincidunt, et ornare nunc facilisis. Mauris tincidunt ac tortor nec tincidunt. Cras velit nibh, scelerisque a pulvinar consequat, vehicula a sem. Sed ultricies metus sit amet feugiat egestas. Cras eget aliquam sem. Sed sit amet purus dapibus, tristique justo at, lobortis ligula. Nam vitae ligula in magna molestie iaculis. Vivamus gravida placerat dapibus. Mauris eget molestie elit, facilisis rutrum nunc. Vivamus suscipit, nisl sed varius eleifend, dui erat semper diam, vel elementum neque lacus a ante. Nulla varius iaculis egestas. Quisque porttitor lacinia tristique. Aliquam ornare nibh sit amet tortor rhoncus, id accumsan nulla feugiat. Nunc pellentesque consectetur dapibus. Vestibulum sit amet lobortis augue. Cras justo nisl, ultricies molestie congue ut, ultrices et velit. Nam consectetur ligula vehicula consectetur dapibus. Etiam tempor condimentum massa quis dictum. Nunc semper, nunc quis tincidunt auctor, ipsum massa cursus lectus, accumsan posuere lectus magna eget lorem. Maecenas non vehicula libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla imperdiet eros at magna mattis, et interdum metus rutrum. Sed semper sed odio sit amet tempor. Aenean sed odio efficitur, congue ligula nec, tempor augue. Nam nec tristique arcu. Aenean aliquam mollis tincidunt. Maecenas et leo quis ex aliquet euismod. Sed et ex eget nisl varius finibus. Aliquam nec lorem in massa venenatis gravida. Quisque non nibh sed diam pretium ultricies in imperdiet nulla. Fusce eget ornare elit. Mauris id mauris eget ante tempus mattis. Nam non aliquam lorem, nec egestas urna. Quisque consequat libero vitae ligula consectetur imperdiet. Vestibulum nec bibendum felis, quis imperdiet dui. Phasellus viverra ornare sem, sit amet rutrum nisi. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ex, at sagittis lectus imperdiet at. Donec vel nulla sem. Praesent quis aliquam arcu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitsectetur imperdiet. Vestibulum nec bibendum felis, quis imperdiet dui. Phasellus viverra ornare sem, sit amet rutrum nisi. Maecenas lobortis accumsan ex, at sagittis lectus imperdiet at. Donec vel nulla sem. Praesent quis aliquam arcu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

and the jQuery

```
$('a[href="#page-1"').click(function () {
$('.wrapper').animate({
    marginLeft: '0'
}, 1000);
return false;
});
$('a[href="#page-2"').click(function () {
$('.wrapper').animate({
    marginLeft: '-100%'
}, 1000);
return false;
});
$('a[href="#page-3"').click(function () {
$('.wrapper').animate({
    marginLeft: '-200%'
}, 1000);
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the footer appear at the bottom of each page, you will have to place it in each page rather than having one footer placed after all of the pages.  Like this:

```
<div id="page-1">
    Content for page 1
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
<div id="page-2">
    Content for page 2
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
<div id="page-3">
    Content for page 3
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnbBS/33/

All of the javascript is a lot to post here, so I will post the javascript for scrolling to page one and you can figure out how to apply it to the other pages:

```
$('a[href="#page-1"').click(function () {
    $("#page-1").css("height", "auto");
    $("#page-2").css("height", "auto");
    $("#page-3").css("height", "auto");
$('.wrapper').animate({
    marginLeft: '0'
}, 1000, function () {
    $("#page-2").css("height", "100px");
    $("#page-3").css("height", "100px");
    $("#page-2").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("#page-3").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
return false;
});
```

Basically you want to set the height of all other pages to 100px and hide the overflow when the animation is complete so the scroll bar is removed if the current page doesn't need it. All pages should have their height set back to auto during the animation so they look normal when you scroll sideways past them. Also don't forget to set all pages except for page 1 to the reduced height and hidden overflow on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#page-2").css("height", "100px");
    $("#page-3").css("height", "100px");
    $("#page-2").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("#page-3").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Comment: your demo works great in chrome but if FF it doesnt work, the footer on page 2 and three isn't there and the page heights are set to 100px and the text is missing. Thanks for the input, ill try and sort that bit out

Comment: figured it out there was a missing closing ] in the a[href="#page-1 calls    http://jsfiddle.net/qnbBS/34/

Answer (score 0):

Put this CSS in your code:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 300%;
    height: auto;
    background: #263729;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.page {
    width: 33.3333%;
    float:left;
    background: #992213;
    padding-bottom: 2000px;
    margin-bottom: -2000px;
}
.footer {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: added that   http://jsfiddle.net/qnbBS/31/ but it made no difference except to make the page bigger. I want the page to be the size of its conent

Comment: Well, all divs have the same height... That's what you want or I don`t understand... sorry

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the footer , body and wrapper class and that is what you want.

**Css :**

```
html , body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 300%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: #263729;
}
.page {
    width: 33.3333%;
    float:left;
    background: #992213;
    min-height: auto;
}
#page-1 {
    background: #0C717A;
}
#page-2 {
    background: #009900;
}
#page-3 {
    background: #0000FF;
}
a {
    color:#FFF;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background:red;

}
.simulate {
    height:auto;
}
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qngxzf2s/)